# Как отобразить медиа файлы в шаблоне Django?

Tags: python, django

```
# models.py
class Catalog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='catalog_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# views.py
def description(request, catalog_id):
    catalog = Catalog.objects.get(id=catalog_id)
    desc = catalog.description
    page_header = 'Catalog description'
    context = {'desc': desc,
               'catalog': catalog,
               'page_header': page_header}
    return render(request, 'catalog/description.html', context)

# в шаблоне:
{% if catalog.image %}
    <img src="{{ catalog.image.url }}" alt="111">
{% endif %}

# settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

в просмотре кода страницы:

```
<img src="/media/catalog_images/640px-Breaded_Cat_1.jpg" alt="111">
```

по факту картинка в папке есть, но не отображает на странице
в консоли пишет:

```
[11/Apr/2017 21:08:37] "GET /catalog/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1029
Not Found: /media/catalog_images/640px-Breaded_Cat_1.jpg
[11/Apr/2017 21:08:37] "GET /media/catalog_images/640px-Breaded_Cat_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2277
```

Comment: А директория действительно такая есть `MEDIA_ROOT`? А файл точно существует?

Answer (score 2):

Если в качестве сервера статики вы **временно** используете dev сервер, то Вам нужно добавить маршруты в свой urlconf

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
 #    ...

   ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) \
              + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: увы, не помогло

Comment: вы перезагрузили дев сервер после внесения изменений?

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот так работает:

urls.py

```
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
...    
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }),
...
]
```

Answer (score -1):

попробуй вот так:

```
 <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{catalog.image.path.url}}" alt="">
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: это сделает `/media/media/.....` так что работать не будет